# Clarification on Lagrange's Theorem and the group $Z_n$ of integers modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I want to show that $Z_3 \leq Z_6 \leq Z_{12}$.

Since $|Z_3|$ and $|Z_6|$ divide $|Z_{12}|$, then they must be subgroups of $Z_{12}$. Similarly, $Z_3 $ is a subgroup of $Z_6$. I feel like here I am using the converse of Lagrange's Theorem. Does the converse hold? If not, what other easy way can we use to show that $Z_3 \leq Z_6 \leq Z_{12}$?

So just to see if I have gotten Lagrange's Theorem: I can only use Lagrange's theorem if we know, for example, that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. In other words, if we already know that $H \leq G$, then it must be the case that $|H|$ divides $|G|$. Correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. The statement of Lagrange's Theorem is that IF $H\leq G$ is a subgroup and $G$ is finite, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. The converse of Lagrange's Theorem is in general not true, but there are partial converses of this, namely the Sylow Theorems/Cauchy's Theorem.

A counterexample to this is given by $A_4\leq S_4$, the alternating group. The order of $A_4$ is $4!/2=12$, but there is no subgroups of order $6$.

Comment: are there subsets of order $6$ in $A_4$ though ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Subsets of order of $6$? Yeah, just pick any $6$ elements, and that's a subset with cardinality $6$.

Answer (score 2):

The converse does not hold. For example, $|Z_4| = 4$ divides $|Z_2 \times Z_2| = 4$ (and vice versa) but neither of these groups are subgroups of the other, as this would force the groups to be isomorphic, which they are not.

**Hint** On the other hand, the groups $Z_p$ are each generated by a single element $g$, (for example, we can always take $g = [1]$). In our case $p = 12$; for any generator $g$, what can we say about the group generated by $g^2$?